# Changing COLAB main account. How to change which email / drive my colab should be linked to?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have two accounts on gmail and both are open at the same time: Account_1@gmail.com and Account_2@gmail.com

When I open https://colab.research.google.com/ and paste a github link, the colab connects to Account_1@gmail.com by default.

How do I change settings so that each time i open Colab it links to Account_2@gmail.com?

- What I have tried*

1. I seem to get around this when i open a colab file from github and then when saving the file as, i change the gmail account at the top right before.
2. I've tried looking for settings in Colab that allow me to register a  'main' email account but i dont see to find this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case you haven't figured it out yet. All the google applications which you open in a web browser tend to start with the google account which is set to default on `accounts.google`. Or if you're opening a link to COLAB notebook from a page, the same google account used on that page will be used to open the notebook.

So the account which you want to open COLAB in by default, opened by typing in the URL, must be set as the default account. In this case Account_2@gmail.com should be set to default.

[Here](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/change-default-google-account-in-seconds/) is one way how to find and change the default account.

**NOTE:** This will force all the applications from google to start with the default (Account_2@gmail.com) account.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's one year later. But I recently encountered the same issue. The way worked for me is to simply add `/?authuser=<profile#>` at the end of `https://colab.research.google.com`.

For example, I have two profiles (see image below). If I want to **OPEN Colab** with **profile2**, (the 2nd profile) simply use the link `https://colab.research.google.com/?authuser=1` (profile1's id is 0).

[image]